# How to do Windows 8.1 "Now Playing" global audio playback

Tags: c#, audio, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, mediaelement

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 store app, and I am using the Hub Control for the base.

While I've successfully figured out how to do global audio playback using the MediaElement control, what I can't figure out is how to have a "now playing" system similar to Audible's app.

I would like for the main hub control page to have a larger "now playing" control, and on the individual item pages have some kind of smaller control at the top-right of the screen.

I've read through all the documentation and tutorials I could find on media playback, but I can't seem to find anything about how to do this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `UserControl` that fits your needs.

Create two `VisualStates` for it, small and large.

Then hook into your HubControl's [`SectionsInViewChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.sectionsinviewchanged.aspx) event.

On the removal of your main page, go to the smaller `VisualState`, then on adding it back in, go back to the larger `VisualState`. You can also use a `VisualTransition` to make a nice animation between the two.

Comment: Does this handle the issue of navigation stopping the audio/video? Currently, that's my biggest holdup: I need the audio to keep playing and I need to be able to control it whichever page I am on.

Comment: For that, you need to be using the [`SystemMediaTransportControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263187.aspx).

Comment: From my understanding, the SystemMediaTransportControls are for the system-wide controls when the user uses the hardware buttons. I actually have that part working and can play audio when you switch to another app.

What I can't get to work is how Audible's app is able to have playback controls on their main page as well as on every page you navigate to. Being able to control the playing audio from every page.

Comment: You can use the same `SystemMediaTransportControls` as your 'system-wide' media player. You can then have your media control modify the values on that system player in the same way. If you create a custom `UserControl` to do this, then you'll only have to do it once. Unless you're asking how to have a single `MediaElement` which 'follows' the user from page to page?

Comment: I was thinking of the single MediaElement approach, but the custom UserControl method could work as well.